# ls not available in alpine after pivot_root

Tags: linux, containers, alpine-linux

I am trying to build a container from scratch by following this tutorial (https://techtalk.digitalpress.blog/building-a-container-from-scratch-part-2/). I'm trying to isolate the filesystem by mounting a new root filesystem (alpine). However, after I performed `pivot_root`, `ls` is no longer available to me. I also echoed the $PATH in case that is useful for root causing.

I assume ls is not available in alpine. How might I be able to perform ls?

Does anyone have any idea how I might be able to have access to `ls` again? Here are the commands I tried:

```
wget https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.18/releases/aarch64/alpine-minirootfs-3.18.5-aarch64.tar
tar -xvf alpine-minirootfs-3.18.5-aarch64.tar.gz -C alpine

unshare --user --map-root-user --pid --mount-proc --mount --fork bash
mount --bind alpine alpine
mkdir alpine/oldrootfs
cd alpine
pivot_root . oldrootfs

ls
# bash: /bin/ls: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
echo $PATH
# /home/brianshih/.cargo/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin
```

Comment: Your question needs to be self-contained. What's in the current directory when you `pivot_root` and in particular where within it is the `ls` binary you expect to be there?